# How to sum time in php from a json file?

Tags: php, json, time, sum

I have an API from a .json url that gives me an ID, the distance, and the duration in HH:MM format.

```
[
    {
        "id": "210",
        "distance": "299",
        "duration": "01:31"
    },
    {
        "id": "209",
        "distance": "279",
        "duration": "01:22"
    },
    {
        "id": "209",
        "distance": "261",
        "duration": "01:15"
    }
]
```

I'd like to make the sum of an ID's duration so that here 01:22 + 01:15 would give me 02:37 but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help ?

Thanks,
Snax

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` to do the addition part of the problem - firstly though you decode the data and iterate through it, like this:

```
$json=json_decode('[
    {
        "id": "210",
        "distance": "299",
        "duration": "01:31"
    },
    {
        "id": "209",
        "distance": "279",
        "duration": "01:22"
    },
    {
        "id": "209",
        "distance": "261",
        "duration": "01:15"
    }
]');

$t=0;
foreach( $json as $obj )$t+=strtotime( $obj->duration );
echo date( 'H:i', $t );
```

Result:

```
04:08
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi again, following your example, I tried this:

```$t = 0;
foreach($json as $obj) {
   if($obj->id == '209') {
      $t+=strtotime($obj->duration);
      print_r(date('H:i', $t));
   }
}```

The result is that I only had the first key shown (1:22), and the following warning:  
**Warning**: date() expects parameter 2 to be int, float given in /www/hours.php on line 25

Any idea why it doesn't work ?